# Create database from psql: Peer authentication failed

Tags: postgresql

I have installed Postgresql on Ubuntu.My users

```
postgres=# \du 
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 mark      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 jh        |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

When I try

```
sudo -u postgres psql createdb rates
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "rates"
```

I want to create rates db for role name mark.How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createdb` is not an SQL command, so you don't execute it from the database client, but from the shell.

Try

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE rates'
```

or

```
sudo -u postgres createdb rates
```